# Flexslider sticks on first frame

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, flexslider

http://dev.marramwines.com/

This is the site I'm working on.  I've used Jquery Flexslider.  When I use animation: "fade", it sticks on the first slide forever before it goes on to the rest, which rotate at the normal speed.
It works fine when I switch it to slide, but I don't want to use slide in this instance because some of the images have white space where that purple circle is.

Here is my script:

```
  <script>
//// Flexslider homepage slideshow
//



  $(window).load(function() {

 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        animation: "fade",
        //direction: "vertical",
        controlNav: false,               
        directionNav: false,
        initDelay: 0
    });
 });

</script>
```

Has anyone seen this before, or know what it might be?  I've just copied a fresh flexslider file over..

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Adding this to my css solved it for me:

```
.slides li {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Did you have `.flexslider` class in the element that wraps the `<ul class="slides">`? The [Getting started documentation](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) fails to point out that **both** classes (`.flexslider .slides`) are important for the flexslider.css to work.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is a bug.
I just shifted the first frame to start from, and now it works:

```
this.dom.find('.flexslider').flexslider({
    // your options
    startAt: -1
});
```

With a positive number it doesn't work, but with this hack it starts correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had the flexslider.css commented out.  There was also some lightbox JS that had an error in it, which I removed.  It works now.